# polymer /deep/ selector is not working in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, polymer, shadow-dom

I trying to rearrange layouts when device screen is resized, so i do this:

```
if(screenOrientation == SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        document.querySelector("html /deep/ [landscape-horizontal]").removeAttribute('vertical');
        document.querySelector("html /deep/ [landscape-horizontal]").setAttribute('horizontal', '');
}
```

This is working in the desktop machine correctly, but in mobile (both android phone, tablet and iOS simulator) i got this error:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'webkitMatchesSelector' on 'Element': 'html /deep/ [landscape-horizontal]' is not a valid selector.", source: bower_components/platform/platform.js (0)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem via CSS:

```
<style shim-shadowdom>

body[portrait] /deep/ [layout][horizontal][landscape], body[landscape] /deep/ [layout][horizontal][portrait] {
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body[portrait] /deep/ [layout][vertical][landscape], body[landscape] /deep/ [layout][vertical][portrait] {
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

</style>
```

Now i change "landscape" and "portrait" attributes in body on screen size changes. This is working in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently an [open issue](https://github.com/Polymer/ShadowDOM/issues/436) to support this in the Shadow DOM polyfill. It works on Chrome 35+, because that's using native shadow dom.

Comment: Thanks, now i understand. But have a way to work deep query in unsupported browsers? (Thanks for this work! I watched your presentation in IO14, it all is awesome :) )

Answer (score 0):

With Platform version ≥0.4.0 you can now use the `/deep/` combinator without fear, it's been polyfilled for non-native browsers.

```
document.querySelector('html /deep/ [landscape-horizontal]');
```

Comment: Thanks, now i understand. But have a way to work deep query in unsupported browsers?

Comment: Updated my answer, this is now polyfilled by the polymer platform.