# Polymer 1.0 on Firefox, Safari /deep/ selector not working

Tags: firefox, safari, polymer, shadow-dom, polyfills

Can someone please explain to me why in Safari and Firefox, things like

```js
Polymer.dom(document.body).querySelectorAll('body /deep/ div.some-class')
```

result in **`SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified`**?

I thought deep linking was polyfilled on non-shadow-DOM browsers.

I also get the same error thrown on selectors with /deep/ in them, if they define a CSS "variable" upon document load

For example, my main index.php contains `<link rel="import" href="shell/styles.html"/>`, which has the following:

```js
html /deep/ paper-button { /* OK */
    height: 46px;
}

html /deep/ paper-icon-button { /* Throws error */
    --paper-icon-button-ink-color: var(--colorWhite);
}
```

Any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: OK, the first part of the question - I think you're supposed to use `Polymer.dom(element.root).querySelector` to search inside shadow DOM, I guess you can't use /deep/ selector like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [polymer /deep/ selector is not working in mobile devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858786/polymer-deep-selector-is-not-working-in-mobile-devices)